# Stream Output of Predictions in Keras

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have an LSTM in Keras that I am training to predict on time series data.  I want the network to output predictions on each timestep, as it will receive a new input every 15 seconds.  So what I am struggling with is the proper way to train it so that it will output h_0, h_1, ..., h_t, as a constant stream as it receives x_0, x_1, ...., x_t as a stream of inputs.  Is there a best practice for doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable statefulness in your LSTM layers by setting [`stateful=True`](http://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#recurrent). This changes the behavior of the layer to always use the state of the previous invocation of the layer instead of resetting it for each `layer.call(x)`.

For example an LSTM layer with 32 units with batch size 1, sequence length 64 and feature length 10:

```
LSTM(32, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=(1,64,10))
```

With this successive calls of `predict` will use the previous states.

Comment: And so .reset_states() would be the function to start a new sequence of inputs?  Very cool, thank you!

Comment: Yep. Forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: @nemo I have a followup question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313673/lstm-with-keras-for-mini-batch-training-and-online-testing). Would you mind taking a look?